# In Angular 2, what is the use of private components (components not exported)

Tags: angular

I understand that by exporting the components, a module can make them available to use in any modules those import it. But I am just wondering what would be the "useful" scenario where these components are not exported (or kept as private/local), but are just declared in it's parent module.

Answer (score 1):

There's a methodology called lazy loading in Angular (as well as other forms of) development. The idea would be that each route, or family of routes would be their own module, with all of the components declared in the module. You would not export the components.

Instead where you configure your app routing, instead of passing a component for a route you would import the children of the Module you created for that route.

However some assets may need to be shared across the different routes. Maybe that would be a certain modal, or a navbar. Those components would be included in a module typically referred to as a `SharedModule`, and they would be exported from that module. The `SharedModule` would then be added as an import, and then your isolated modules you created for your routing would have access to those shared components (and likely pipes as well).

I hope that paints a decent picture as to how/why you would use modules, import modules, export components and what not. If you're interested in seeing what I mean you can [take a dig through this codebase](https://github.com/MichaelSolati/fempire-angular/tree/master), specifically take a look at the file `src/app/app-routing.module.ts` for routing to modules, `src/app/shared/shared.module.ts` for exported components and what not, and maybe `src/app/home/home.module.ts` which will show you how I bring in the `SharedModule` but do not export anything from that module.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not sure I got it right yet. In lazy loading, it points to a module in which the specific router module is imported. In that routing module, we still need to import the home.component to use it. So what advantage is there to define the HomeComponent in the home.module? I will spend some more time reading your code, but just wanted to throw this out here.

Comment: The point/idea is that when we take out application into production, instead of bundling up all of the components, modules and what not, we create different chunks, and as we navigate through the application we load in those chunks (which are modules) as needed.

Because each route goes to a Module, we declare some more routing in that module, for the subroutes in it.

Comment: I gave a talk about this sort of thing a month or so ago, if you [watch maybe 4 minutes of this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bhd2ayEE9mg&t=397s), you'll probably get a better jist of what I mean.

Comment: This was the thing I was looking for. From angular documentation "If you don't export a class, it stays private, visible only to other component declared in this NgModule"